# Mapping properties from base class doesn't work using ExplicitExpansion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

AutoMapper is not projecting query in EF when using `ExplicitExpansion` in a property that is defined in a base class. The following code shows the models:

```
/*********** Source Types ***********/
class EntityBase
{
    public Guid? CreatedById { get; set; }
    public Guid? ModifiedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModifiedById")]
    public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Script : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}


/*********** Destination Types ***********/
class EntityBaseModel
{
    public Guid? CreatedById { get; set; }
    public Guid? ModifiedById { get; set; }
    public UserModel CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public UserModel ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

class UserModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class ScriptModel : EntityBaseModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public new UserModel ModifiedBy { get; set; } //notice the 'new' here? this will work
}
```

I'm using the following mapping configuration:

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Script, ScriptModel>()
            .MaxDepth(1)
            .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
            .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());
        });
```

The following test will fail, but it shouldn't... it should fetch the `CreatedBy` property because I've explicitly said so:

```
/// <summary>
    /// This will fail, but it shouldn't.
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Map_CreatedBy()
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            var model = context.Scripts.Include("CreatedBy").ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(null, "CreatedBy").FirstOrDefault();
            Assert.IsNotNull(model);
            Assert.IsNotNull(model.CreatedBy);
        }
    }
```

I've also tried these configurations, but it doesn't work either

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<EntityBase, EntityBaseModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<User, UserModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Script, ScriptModel>()
            .MaxDepth(1)
            .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
            .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());
        });
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<EntityBase, EntityBaseModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<User, UserModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Script, ScriptModel>()
            .IncludeBase<EntityBase, EntityBaseModel>()
            .MaxDepth(1)
            .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
            .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());
        });
```

Is there something wrong with my mapping configuration? Is that an automapper bug?

Here's the full repro: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhH0QYI81F61gtIx0q27BZ05EM-xQA

Answer (score 0):

```
    cfg.CreateMap<User, UserModel>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Script, ScriptModel>()
        .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
        .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());

    var model = context.Scripts.ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(s=>s.CreatedBy).FirstOrDefault()
```

This works for me with the latest version.

Comment: yes, passing the expression indeed works, but when using the overload that accepts a `string` it fails. This is definitely a **bug**. I need to pass `string` because that's what I have; it comes from a web request...

Comment: `context.Scripts.Include("CreatedBy").ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(null, "CreatedBy").FirstOrDefault()` this isn't working for me with `6.1.1` version... any idea why? `CreatedBy` property is null.. and it shouldn't be.

Comment: The latest version is the [MyGet](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/The-MyGet-Build) build. The Include is useless with EF6, it might be needed on EF Core.